# use slideUp to show div in jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I write this code.
but I want when click on my image, div open from bottom to up. this code do Vice versa.
but I dont know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".button").slideToggle('slow');
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $(".button").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container resolution-list text-center">
  <div class="resolution">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/c2.png" id="img"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="button text-center">
    <ul class="text-center">
      <li><button class="btn0" type="button">240</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn0" type="button">450</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn0" type="button">700</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn0" type="button">1024</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you need. It is sliding up, but you have bound also the whole document on click. Is there a specific reason why?

Comment: I found it thank you:                                       
`code`     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(".button").effect('slide', { direction: 'down', mode: 'show' },500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).click(function(){
            $(".button").slideUp("slow");
        });
    });

Comment: then please select the "Answer your own question" so this topic can be closed.